# Как организовать angular universal проект с бэкендом на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, angular4, server-side-rendering

Есть проект на 5-ом Angular с сервер сайд рендерингом. (Angular Universal). Заливаю его на digital ocean, билдю и запускаю server.js, отвечающий за рендеринг. Но бэкенд проекта у меня тоже на node.js. Означает ли это, что я должен запускать по сути два сервера, или два node.js процесса - один для universal, второй для backend api? Нормальная ли вообще это практика?

Answer (score 1):

ssr может работать на том же сервере просто надо завернуть все get запросы под angular route а (/api/ route) на ваш backend